# I'm trying to use a while loop to remove letters from a string until there are none left. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string word;
    cout << "please enter a word: ";
    getline(cin, word);
    int str_size;
    word.size() = str_size;
// the line above says "word must be modifiable". new to coding so not sure how to fix it?
// also haven't tested anything below this point yet.
    while (str_size) {
        word.resize(str_size - 1, '\0');
    }

    string end;
    getline(cin, end);
    return 0;
    }
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here. Am i just going about it the wrong way?

Comment: You never update `str_size` so the while loop is effectively infinite.

Comment: The error message is because you've got the assignment order wrong.   It should be `str_size = word.size()`  not `word.size() = str_size`.     And the while loop is infinite, since the call of `word.resize()` does not change `str_size`.     Accordingly, voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line:

```
word.size() = str_size;
```

you are trying to assign a value to the temporary value returned by `.size()`. However, the `operator=` needs an lvalue (i.e. a variable that has a name) on the left hand side.

So what you need is:

```
str_size = word.size();
```

To actually remove letters from a string, you could use some algorithms such as [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) that lets you avoid writing any loops at all.

Comment: wow... I've been looking at this for an hour now. thanks a bunch

Comment: wont let me for 10 min :(

Comment: That's a good thing. It's to prevent users from blindly accepting the first answer they get. Take the time to make sure that this actually works, and you understand the reasoning behind it :)

Comment: ***I've been looking at this for an hour now.*** This is where if you had an IDE with a debugger you would have seen the error in a minute. I recommend getting a debugger and learning how to use it.